# Ember model properties with uppercase chars not being set

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I just started playing around with ember and ember-data, and the back of my head is red from all the scratching. I'm using latest ember and ember-data with the RESTAdapter, and getting json data from a rest service.

My problem was that some properties on models were simply not being set. Running something like **App.store.find(App.Version,2).get('siteId')** in the console would simply return null.

I discovered that this was only for properties containing uppercase characters. When changing the rest service to only serve lowercase characters (and fixing the corresponding ember model, of course), all properties were set correctly. Is this intentional, or have I screwed something up?

Comment: I think this is because the default RESTAdapter conventionnaly expects lower and snake case in the response hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data's RESTAdapter expects naming to be done in a certain way from the server. This can be changed with something like:

`App.Adapter.map('App.Version', {
  site_id: { key: 'SITEID' }
});`

There are some details about this at the following link:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md

Specifically look at revision 3 and 5.

Comment: Ah, thank you. keyForAttributeName on my serializer did the trick. Can't believe I didn't see that.